# TypeScript PostgreSQL TypeORM convert raw result to entity

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

Unfortunately it seems as if TypeORM does not provide a API to convert raw results from either `EntityManager.query` or `QueryBuilder.execute` to entities. However, https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/6803 indicates that you can use TypeORM internal classes like [PlainObjectToNewEntityTransformer](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_query_builder_transformer_plainobjecttonewentitytransformer_.plainobjecttonewentitytransformer.html) or [RawSqlResultsToEntityTransformer](http://typeorm-doc.exceptionfound.com/classes/rawsqlresultstoentitytransformer.html).

I have tried both with little luck.

`RawSqlResultsToEntityTransformer`

```
 async updateOne(queryConfig: UpdateOne<User>): Promise<User> {
    const query: UpdateQueryBuilder<User> = this.createUpdateQuery(queryConfig);
    const { raw, affected } = await query.execute();

    if (!affected) {
      throw new HttpException('Could not update user', HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }

    const queryRunner = this.dataSource.createQueryRunner();

    const relationIdLoader = new RelationIdLoader(
      this.dataSource.manager.connection,
      queryRunner,
      query.expressionMap.relationIdAttributes,
    );

    const relationCountLoader = new RelationCountLoader(
      this.dataSource.manager.connection,
      queryRunner,
      query.expressionMap.relationCountAttributes,
    );

    const rawRelationIdResults = await relationIdLoader.load(raw);

    const rawRelationCountResults = await relationCountLoader.load(raw);

    const transformer = new RawSqlResultsToEntityTransformer(
      query.expressionMap,
      this.dataSource.driver,
      rawRelationIdResults,
      rawRelationCountResults,
    );

    console.log('raw', raw);

    const entities = transformer.transform(raw, query.expressionMap.mainAlias);

    console.log('entities', entities);

    return entities[0] as User;
  }
```

The console output

```
  console.log
    raw [
      {
        created_at: 2023-03-15T20:12:41.905Z,
        updated_at: 2023-03-15T20:12:42.003Z,
        id: 1,
        email: 'someone1@email.com',
        first_name: 'user_1',
        last_name: 'user_1',
        organization_id: 1,
        role_id: 1
      }
    ]

      at UserRepository.updateOne (user/user.repository.ts:228:13)

  console.log
    entities []
```

`PlainObjectToNewEntityTransformer`

```
 async updateOne(queryConfig: UpdateOne<User>): Promise<User> {
    const query: UpdateQueryBuilder<User> = this.createUpdateQuery(queryConfig);
    const { raw, affected } = await query.execute();

    if (!affected) {
      throw new HttpException('Could not update user', HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
 
    const metadata = this.dataSource.getMetadata(User);
    const transformer = new PlainObjectToNewEntityTransformer();

    const updatedUser: User = metadata.create(
      this.dataSource.createQueryRunner(),
    );

    transformer.transform(updatedUser, raw[0], metadata);

    console.log('raw', raw);
    console.log('updatedUser', updatedUser);

    return updatedUser;
}
```

Console output

```
  console.log
    [
      {
        created_at: 2023-03-15T20:37:33.440Z,
        updated_at: 2023-03-15T20:37:33.533Z,
        id: 1,
        email: 'someone1@email.com',
        first_name: 'user_1',
        last_name: 'user_1',
        organization_id: 1,
        role_id: 1
      }
    ]

      at UserRepository.updateOne (user/user.repository.ts:244:13)

  console.log
    x User { id: 1, email: 'someone1@email.com' }
```

the user entity

```
@Entity({ name: 'user' })
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', name: 'email', nullable: false })
  email: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', name: 'first_name', nullable: false })
  firstName: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', name: 'last_name', nullable: false })
  lastName: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', name: 'password', nullable: false })
  password: string;

  @Column({ name: 'organization_id', type: 'int', nullable: true })
  organizationId: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Organization, (organization) => organization.users, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'organization_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  organization: Organization;

  @Column({ name: 'role_id', type: 'int', nullable: false })
  roleId: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Role, (role) => role.users, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'role_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  role: Role;
}
```

How can I transform raw results from `EntityManager.query` or a query builder result (update, delete, or insert with `QueryBuilder.returning('*')` with either [PlainObjectToNewEntityTransformer](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_query_builder_transformer_plainobjecttonewentitytransformer_.plainobjecttonewentitytransformer.html) or [RawSqlResultsToEntityTransformer](http://typeorm-doc.exceptionfound.com/classes/rawsqlresultstoentitytransformer.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing and came up with this solution. Maybe this will help you too.

This solution is a) only to clarify the principle and can be further optimized and b) has not yet been put through its paces.

```
const result = await qb.returning('*').execute();
const columnsMap = new Map<string, string>(
  this.repo.metadata.columns.map((c) => [c.databaseName, c.propertyName]),
);

const entities = result.raw.map((raw) => {
  const obj = this.repo.create();

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(raw)) {
    const propertyName = columnsMap.get(key);
    if (!propertyName) continue;

    (obj as any)[propertyName] = value;
  }

  return obj;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`RawSqlResultsToEntityTransformer` is the correct way to do this.

But it's only known to work with `SelectQueryBuilder`. I suspect the reason you're having trouble in the given example is that you are trying to map the results from an `UpdateQueryBuilder`, which might not produce the metadata required to perform the mapping.

`PlainObjectToNewEntityTransformer` is not the right tool. It has a different purpose, which is to turn a plain object representing an entity into a class instance of that entity. This won't do any property<->column name mapping at all, as you observed.

The easiest solution in this scenario is going to be to run the update first, get the IDs of the affected rows, and then use a `SelectQueryBuilder` to fetch the data from those rows that you want to map to entities.